# Hide photoshop resizing controls

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop, I accidentally turned on something that shows the resize controls every time I select a layer and I can't figure out how to turn it off. It goes away when I deselect View > Extras but that also hides my guides.

Comment: When you find out, let me know how to turn them on.  lol.

Comment: What do you mean by resizing controls? What environment are you working in... Windows, Mac, ...? What version of Photoshop are you using... CS3, CS4, CS5?

Comment: I am on a Mac using CS4. They are like the free transform controls and when you try to resize or move the origin, free transform is engaged. I keep moving the origin by accident and they are very distracting.

Comment: So when you click on different layers, the free transform turns on?

Comment: Sort of. The resize controls (including change origin, rotate etc.) appear on the selected layer and when you click on a control free transform is activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the move tool. On top, in the options bar, de-select the "Show Transform Controls" option.

Comment: You are my hero.